# sqlite3 compile error with llvm compiler

Tags: objective-c, c, sqlite, compiler-errors, llvm

Compiling my project on new xcode4 using `llvm 2.0` compiler I get a strange error coming from standard `<sqlite3.h>` header. Problem is with the following line:

```
//<sqlite3.h>
typedef struct sqlite3 sqlite3;
```

Error message:

```
In file included from /Projects/trunk/MyProj/Classes/StatsProvider.m:14:
Elaborated type refers to a non-tag type in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

Using GCC 4.2 project compiles with no problem

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: you are compiling sqlite as C++ code, whereas you should compile it as plain C code.  class/struct keywords implicitly introduce a typedef in C++, but not so in C.

Comment: That was it - source type for that file was explicitly set to obj-c++ for some reason, changing it to obj-c solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the error message as the compiler complaining about using `struct sqlite3` when it hasn't seen a struct declaration with that name. Struct names are in a special "tag-space".

My next guess is that the new compiler is stricter than the old one, and has found a bug.